# JQuery Accessing the previous tag text in <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox with id `xxxx`,I'm trying to access `WaLia` text from `<td>` from that checkbox so that i can make ajax request with that text.

```
<tbody style="border:1px solid transparent; background-color:#242424; color:#A1A6AB; text-align: left;">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 14px;">01</td>
    <td>WaLia</td>
    <td>Walia@gmail.com</td>
    <td>+1 222 555 6666</td>
    <td>Ontario, Canada</td>
    <td>
      <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" id="xxxx">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

---

So far manage to do:

```
<script>
  $("#xxxx").click(function(e){
    if (e.target.checked){
      var msg = $(this).prev().text(); // need "WaLia" here
      console.log(msg);
      //alert(1);
    }else{
      console.log('lol');
      //alert(2);
    }

  });
</script>
```

Please note there are more `<tr>` objects are present within `<tbody>` & each has unique `checkbox` id.

Comment: Id better not duplicate in HTML, u can use class selector .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth(1)').text()` for fetching nearest `tr` then find `nth` `td` element inside that `tr` and then access its text.

**Note** Don't use `$("#xxxx").click` as it will only assign click event to first element with id `xxxx`. This is how `id selector(#)` works. You can use `$("[id='xxxx'").click` instead of that.

```js
$("[id='xxxx'").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    var msg = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth(1)').text(); // need "WaLia" here
    console.log(msg);
    //alert(1);
  } else {
    console.log('lol');
    //alert(2);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody style="border:1px solid transparent; background-color:#242424; color:#A1A6AB; text-align: left;">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 14px;">01</td>
      <td>WaLia</td>
      <td>Walia@gmail.com</td>
      <td>+1 222 555 6666</td>
      <td>Ontario, Canada</td>
      <td>
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" id="xxxx">
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 14px;">01</td>
      <td>WaLia123</td>
      <td>Walia123@gmail.com</td>
      <td>+1 222 555 1234</td>
      <td>Torrento, Canada</td>
      <td>
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" id="xxxx">
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation besides the answer.

Comment: I supposed id will be unique for every input.. If id will be the same it's incorrect approach. Better to use class instead of id.

Comment: @MargulanZharkenov I totaly agree with you. It is suppose to be unique. That's why `id` selector `$('#id')` is returning only one element. So as you said it's advisable to use `class` instead of `id` .

Answer (score 2):

You should pick the tr element and then pick the second child where the text located. Then do what you wanted.

```
var parent = $("#xxxx").parent(); // td element of your input
var grandParent = parent.parent(); // tr element
var element = grandParent.children().eq(2); // selecting the second child
console.log(element.text()); // your text
```

Hope it'll help you.

**Upd.:**
If "xxxx" will be the same for every input don't use id. Use class cause id is used in unique cases and class for repeating elements.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
  <td style="padding: 14px;">01</td>
  <td>WaLia123</td>
  <td>Walia123@gmail.com</td>
  <td>+1 222 555 1234</td>
  <td>Torrento, Canada</td>
  <td>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="xxxx"><!--use class, not id!-->
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
$(".xxxx").click(function(e){
    if (e.target.checked){
      var parent= $(this).parent().parent(); // td element of your input
      var grandParent = parent.parent(); // tr element
      var element = grandParent.children().eq(2);
      console.log(element.text());
      //alert(1);
    }else{
      console.log('lol');
      //alert(2);
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use a css selector to get to your element. Assuming the value you want is always in the second `td`, this should work.

```
$(this).parent().parent('td:nth-child(2)');
```

Of course, it would be a lot more reliable if you can put an ID on your element that contains the text and use `getElementById` instead, that way your code isn’t super brittle, vulnerable to breaking with the slightest change of the HTML structure.

Better yet, if you’re generating this HTML, you could just assign the value of your checkbox to be the same as the visible value to the user, then you can just use `e.target.value`

```
<input type="checkbox" value="WaLia" id="xxxx" />

$("#xxxx").click(function(e){
    if (e.target.checked){
      var msg = e.target.value
      console.log(msg);
    } else {
      console.log('lol');
    }
});
```